# How to segue programmatically segue

Tags: swift, interface-builder

I've just finished a Swift tutorial which does not use Interface Builder. It is all programmatic. Everything looks great but now I have to segue back to the storyboard, I am lost.

I'd like to segue from the "Login" button designed in the Audible tutorial to the next view controller I created in my storyboard called "DashboardVC".

Here is a link to the tutorial and source code. https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=382

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is all from code, you don't have segue's; either you have to push a new controller using pushViewController from NavigationController or instantiate a new ViewController, in this case your 'DashboardVC'.

Like this

```
 let viewController = DashboardVC()
 viewController.view.backgroundColor = .blueColor() //example
 navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Or just presenting the controller using this

```
let vc = DashboardVC()
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Using Storyboard, should be like this; the view controller identifier have to be set in the storyboard as well

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"DashboardVC") as! DashboardVC
self.present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thank you Edu. I still don't understand how that is done. If you could direct me to a tutorial that'd be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will give that a go.

Comment: Great to help, that guy makes amazing tutorials.

Comment: Hi Edu, it's not working. I appreciate your help, thank you. I just can't get this code to work with this tutorial. I get a black screen and nothing I've done shows my DashboardVC.

Comment: Let me check the tutorial, I'll let you know

Comment: Thanks Edu. It's pushing over fine but I'm still not seeing Dashboard VC when I run the project. It's like it's stuck in the code.

Comment: @Catherine check my edit again, I just noticed you said you create that view controller on the storyboard

Comment: Thank you again. Can you just confirm where in the project I put that code? Please excuse my newbness. I'd really like to move on from this and really appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to put it in a function event, the function that tells you when to go to the next view controller. I'm here to help so don't worry :)

Comment: In which file? The LoginController, MainNavigationController or DashboardVC?

Comment: In the LoginController, I guess you are validating if there is a tap on the button, once you validate if your login is correct you'll present the DashboardVC, and that code will do the work.

Comment: I think what has confused me is the collectionview. For example, the LoginController, the MainNavigationController and HomeController (DashboardVC) is referenced in other views inside the collection view. Although I have not resolved this yet you have been a great help Edu, thank you. I have learnt a lot. Mainly, code is much easier than fluffing around with interface builder. I have wasted so much time on this. The solution for me now is to rebuild my DashboardVC in code then initiate the new view to the storyboard from there.

Comment: If there's anyway I can be more helpful, please let me know. Please contact me